# Convert list to params C#

Tags: c#, list, parameters, keyvaluepair

I have this following list:

```
var myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
```

And this function:

```
public void Test(params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] list)
```

How can I do a conversion of the list to params when using the function?
Like that:

```
Test(myList);
```

Comment: `Test(myList.ToArray());`

Comment: `myList.ToArray()`

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You method declaration `KeyValuePair<string, object>[] list` states that it will accept an array so you need to convert your list to array like this

```
Test(myList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the original question, I think it's worth clarifying how the `params` keyword functions.
It has to be a decorator on a 1D array, and simply allows an alternate syntax for calling the function.

For example if we have a string concatenation function:

```
public string Test(string[] names) {
    return String.Join(",", names);
}
```

This can be called using

`Test(new[] { "Fred", "Wilma", "Pebbles"});`

but the inclusion of the `params` keyword simply allows a friendlier looking calling syntax:

```
public string Test(params string[] names) {
    return String.Join(",", names);
}
```

`Test("Fred", "Wilma", "Pebbles");`

I'm not a huge fan of the `params` keyword, but I do sometimes use it to make calling code more readable (as in this example).

So when the OP asks "*How can I do a conversion of the list to params?*", the underlying truth is that you don't, as params is not a type and is simply a "syntactical sugar" feature to give an alternative syntax for passing in an array.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the list to form which is accepted as parameter. In this case convert List to Array

Hence,

```
var arrayParam = mylist.ToArray();
Test(arrayParam);
```